# d3 map only works in Firefox

Tags: google-chrome, firefox, d3.js

So, I have a map in d3 and it is only working in Firefox.  It does not work in chrome.  When I run the map from pre-pros, it works - I'm not sure how prepros works but it seems to deploy a faux server on my local machine.  So with Prepros, regardless of the browser, everything works correctly.  Without running my website on prepros, here are some of the errors- what should I do to ensure cross browser compatibility?  Thanks.

```
//Some of the errors
file:///C:/Users/SXM274/My_Websites/Residents_Website/lib/d3.min.js Failed to load resource: net::ERR_FILE_NOT_FOUND
main2.js:11 initialized
main2.js:37 setting map
d3.v3.js:444 XMLHttpRequest cannot load file:///C:/Users/SXM274/My_Websites/Residents_Website/data/countries.topojson. Cross origin requests are only supported for protocol schemes: http, data, chrome, chrome-extension, https, chrome-extension-resource.xhr.send @ d3.v3.js:444
main2.js:87 callback funtion initialized
main2.js:90 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'objects' of undefined
```

Answer (score 0):

You can't load local file system resources using `XMLHttpRequest` for security reasons. You need to run a web server so that the `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` header can be sent as a response.

You can get around this locally by passing the `--allow-file-access-from-files` flag to Chrome.

### Windows:

```
chrome.exe --allow-file-access-from-files
```

### Mac:

```
open /Applications/Google\ Chrome.app/ --args --allow-file-access-from-files
```